# Updating existing subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, php

There are two Exact Target examples that I would like to implement in a landing page together. The first examples involves the Web Collect demo found here:

help.exacttarget.com/Global/WebCollectCodeSamplesS4/WebCollectCodeSamples.zip

The "Subscribe-Unsubscribe_Multiple_Lists.txt" file in that download is a simple Web Collect form that adds a new subscriber to lists that they check off. I insert my member id as well as the list ids in the appropriate spots and it works great. The problem is, if a subscriber already exists in my database, this form will return an error and not update their desired lists.

That is where this example comes in:

https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscribers_on_lists/

I would like to insert the php script found above to update that subscriber when they hit submit instead of returning a "Subscriber Already Exists" error.

Is this the best route to go for this? Has anyone done something similar?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the SubAction to Add and Update instead of just "sub".  Below should give you this functionality and avoid the error you are seeing.

```
<input type="radio" name="SubAction" value="sub_add_update" checked>
```

Let me know how that works out for you.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, but that did not work

Comment: Are you getting the same error message?  Are you trying to update the All Subscribers list or just individual lists?

Comment: Individual. If I use that value for the sub button, I get the "an error has occurred while attempting to save ur subscriber info" error. This is different than before

Comment: I just tested this out in my own account and got it to work a few different times.  I subscribed initially, updated my subscriber, unsubscribed, and then re-subscribed without any issues.  @user3087325 If you're still having issues, can you open up a support case with ExactTarget - help@exacttarget.com

Comment: I made a stupid mistakes, an this works perfectly! Thank you